# Are there any hard-to-use or unsolvable math equations that have far reaching implications?

Tags: soft-question, big-list

We often talk about mathematical beauty and how they end up describing incredible patterns or phenomena. But are there any mathematical equations that are extremely non-trivial and virtually unsolvable which have strong real-world applications?

**Edit**: I realized that to obtain appropriate answers, I must define the word "ugly." An equation is said to be ugly if it satisfies on or more conditions

1) Large Number of Variables.

2) Describes a trivial phenomena in a non-trivial manner.

3) Is derived using a brute force approach.

Comment: Yes, in particular Navier-Stockes equations : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navier%E2%80%93Stokes_equations

Comment: Sorry, there are no ugly equations. In particular, Navier-Stokes equations are quite beautiful.

Comment: @Igor Rivin Yes, but they are extremely non trivial and have a lot of applications.

Comment: I guess, "ugly" in this context means "overly-instantiated".

Comment: First you need to define what you mean by "ugly", as it's a very subjective notion.

Comment: @IgorRivin I second that. Mathematical equations are always naturally beautiful.

Comment: While it may not qualify as an equation - being a "premouse" is a $\mathcal Q$-condition and I'm pretty sure that most people in Inner Model Theory would say that it is somewhat ugly and all of them would agree that it is of importance.

Comment: beauty in the eye of beholder, this makes "ugliness" a subject of debate, wel in my opinion, i vote for prime numbers conjectures as ugly they are as foretelling they are

Comment: The quadratic formula? Well, I've never liked it... Kind of subjective, though.

Comment: I'm trying to find the precise formula for the electric force between two moving, accelerating charges. It's a nightmare to look at

Comment: The complexity of a formula depends on how much hidden complexity is in the meaning of the variables and the symbols. Everything can be put in a simple formula if you build up a long sequence of definitions and notation.

Comment: @MarcoDisce Right. I bet V = L and P = NP would be pretty ugly if you wrote out the definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following equation is an expression of the fact that matrix multiplication is associative:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{j=1}^{m}\left[a_{ij}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}b_{jk}c_{kl}\right)\right] & = & \sum_{k=1}^{n}\left[\left(\sum_{j=1}^{m}a_{ij}b_{jk}\right)c_{kl}\right]
\end{eqnarray*}

- It is certainly far reaching; matrix computations are carried out constantly.
- As far as I know, it is usually 'derived' simply by writing out the summation on the left and rewriting it as the summation on the right ('brute force').
- Do the entries in the matrices count as variables? If so, then it involves lots of variables.
- It can be re-expressed as simply this: $(f\circ g)\circ h = f\circ(g\circ h)$, where $f,g,h$ are linear transformations between suitable vector spaces.

I would say (and indeed, your criteria seem to agree) that the above equation is "ugly". However, the fourth point above is important: usually, ugly things can be rewritten in more elegant (though, in some situations, less useful) ways.

Another example that illustrates this last point especially well is the definition of the determinant of a matrix. The usual definition that students are introduced to is as some horrible summation involving cofactors etc., rather than the more elegant view as simply the volume scale factor of the unit cube (with a few terms and conditions).

Comment: there's a symmetry here that i find satisfying; hardly ugly

Comment: I think has order, symmetry and compact beauty.

Comment: @MichaelChirico: I agree that there is a certain symmetry here., but there are also symmetries inherent in many of the other examples given. For example, I know nothing of physics, but the Lagrangian for the Standard Model, while horrendously long and complicated, certainly poses an interesting exercise in pattern spotting. At the risk of sounding superstitious, one might say that the presence of some kind of order/symmetry is even a necessary condition for the equation to be far-reaching in its consequences.

Answer (score 10):

The utterly disgusting 8 line equation found [here](http://einstein-schrodinger.com/Standard_Model.pdf) is what happens when you build a Lagrangian for the Standard Model of Physics.

Comment: I am wondering if there is or not a typo in it !

Comment: Why is everything so... packed together, that entire document looks ugly :(

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure if this qualifies as "far-reaching," but the solutions to the general quartic (degree $4$) equation is quite nasty in my opinion.

[This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#Solving_a_quartic_equation) page discusses the solution, but does not actually state an explicit formula.

I would consider this a far reaching problem, as it demostrates the power and limitations of early algebra and leads to the study of group theory, specifically Abel and Galois' work in the insolubility of the quintic.

Comment: I don't know whether or not the general quartic formula has real world significance, since one can calculate the zeroes of any quartic polynomial to arbitrary precision without using it.

Comment: Very good point.

Comment: just saw this, meant no piracy with my own solution! this is what first came to mind for me. quartic is even uglier than cubic, of course!

Comment: Since no one seems to have provided a link to these formulas, [here it is](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Quartic_Formula.svg).

Comment: @Wojowu Thank you! I was searching for that picture.

Answer (score 4):

I think the generic solution for cubic polynomial roots certainly counts.

[ported from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_formula_for_roots)]

$$x_1 = -\frac1{3a}\left(b+\sqrt[3]{\frac{2b^3 - 9abc + 27a^2d + \sqrt{(2b^3 - 9abc + 27a^2d)^2 - 4(b^2-3ac)^3}}{2}}+\frac{b^2-3ac}{\sqrt[3]{\frac{2b^3 - 9abc + 27a^2d + \sqrt{(2b^3 - 9abc + 27a^2d)^2 - 4(b^2-3ac)^3}}{2}}}\right)$$

$$x_2 = -\frac1{3a}\left(b+\frac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}\sqrt[3]{\frac{2b^3 - 9abc + 27a^2d + \sqrt{(2b^3 - 9abc + 27a^2d)^2 - 4(b^2-3ac)^3}}{2}}+\frac{b^2-3ac}{\frac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}\sqrt[3]{\frac{2b^3 - 9abc + 27a^2d + \sqrt{(2b^3 - 9abc + 27a^2d)^2 - 4(b^2-3ac)^3}}{2}}}\right)$$

$$x_3 = -\frac1{3a}\left(b+\frac{-1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}\sqrt[3]{\frac{2b^3 - 9abc + 27a^2d + \sqrt{(2b^3 - 9abc + 27a^2d)^2 - 4(b^2-3ac)^3}}{2}}+\frac{b^2-3ac}{\frac{-1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}\sqrt[3]{\frac{2b^3 - 9abc + 27a^2d + \sqrt{(2b^3 - 9abc + 27a^2d)^2 - 4(b^2-3ac)^3}}{2}}}\right)$$

---

Other potential candidates:

- the PDF of the multivariate normal distribution (certainly ugly enough that we avoid presenting it in intro courses, and I would guess the percentage of people who know what the "bell curve" is intuitively but haven't the slightest of this formula is, is quite large). Not hideous, but it is undoubtedly *ubiquitous*:

$$\varphi(x; \mu, \Sigma, k) = \frac1{\sqrt[k]{2\pi}}|\Sigma|^{-\frac12}e^{-\frac12(x-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu)}$$

- Rademacher's partition counting approximation (relevant for all sorts of computer scientific stuff like graph theory):

$$p(n) = \frac1{\pi\sqrt{2}}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sqrt{k}A_k(n)\frac{d}{dn}\left(\frac1{\sqrt{n-\frac1{24}}}\sinh\left[\frac{\pi}{k}\sqrt{\frac23\left(n-\frac1{24}\right)}\right]\right)$$

$$A_k(n) = \sum_{0\leq m<k; (m, k) = 1}e^{\pi i\left[s(m, k) - \frac{2nm}{k}\right]}$$

Comment: No piracy at all! Glad someone posted the cubic. but moreover, +1 for the first mention of a PDF.